# how to get rid of the 'ERROR -' string and remove the first arrow '->'?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a `log.php`, I want to `substr` a `file_get_contents("application\logs\log.php");` function,

log file contains :

```
ERROR - 2018-09-17 06:51:03 --> Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'Catatan' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 483
ERROR - 2018-09-17 06:51:03 --> Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'Catatan' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 483
ERROR - 2018-09-17 06:51:03 --> Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'Rekomendasi' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 502
ERROR - 2018-09-17 06:51:03 --> Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'Rekomendasi' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 502
ERROR - 2018-09-17 06:51:03 --> Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'name' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 507
ERROR - 2018-09-17 06:51:03 --> Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'name' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 507
```

how to get rid of the `'ERROR -'` string and remove the first arrow `'->'` to be

`2018-09-17 06:51:03 Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'Catatan' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 483`

Comment: What is `show_source`? I'd probably use `awk` for this and only display the fields I wanted, that's not really a PHP answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to give the most flexibility:

```
$err = "ERROR - 2018-09-17 06:51:03 --> Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'Catatan' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 483
ERROR - 2018-09-17 06:51:03 --> Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'Catatan' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 483
ERROR - 2018-09-17 06:51:03 --> Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'Rekomendasi' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 502
ERROR - 2018-09-17 06:51:03 --> Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'Rekomendasi' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 502
ERROR - 2018-09-17 06:51:03 --> Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'name' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 507
ERROR - 2018-09-17 06:51:03 --> Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'name' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 507";
echo preg_replace(array('/(^|\R)ERROR\s*-\s*/', '/(^|\R)(.*?)\s*-->\s*/'), array('$1', '$1$2 '), $err);
```

Output:

```
2018-09-17 06:51:03 Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'Catatan' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 483
2018-09-17 06:51:03 Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'Catatan' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 483
2018-09-17 06:51:03 Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'Rekomendasi' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 502
2018-09-17 06:51:03 Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'Rekomendasi' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 502
2018-09-17 06:51:03 Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'name' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 507
2018-09-17 06:51:03 Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'name' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 507
```

The preg_replace call has two patterns to match: `'/(^|\R)ERROR\s*-\s*/' and '/(^|\R)(.*?)\s*-->\s*/'` and `'$1' and '$1$2 '` are the corresponding replacement strings. Inside those strings, the expression `$1` refers to the first matched group in the pattern (in both cases, that is `(^|\R)` which matches either the beginning of the line or a new line). In the second replacement, `$2` is used to output all the characters from the beginning of the line to the first `-->` i.e. those captured by the second group `(.*?)`.

Comment: @DevoAvidiantoP I've modified my answer so it will work with a multi-line string such as you will get from `file_get_contents()`

Comment: what means array('$1', '$1$2 ') ? @nick

Comment: Hi @DevoAvidiantoP, I've added an explanation to the answer. I hope that helps you. The manual page I linked to also has some good, simpler, examples.